# Aligning Vertically with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have the following html block (image is just something I found on the web). I've used multiple examples and answers from different questions tackling the similar problem I have but I can't seem to figure it out.

What's the proper or best way to align a text vertically beside an image? I'm currently using bootstrap 3.3.6. I tried using different approaches but can't seem to make anything work.

```css
.textContainer {
  display: table;
}

.imageClass {
  margin: 5px;
}

.spanText {
  display: table-cell;
  align-items: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 textContainer">
      <img class="imageClass" width=100 height=100 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg" alt="alt text" />
      <span class="spanText">Need to center</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove your `display: table;` CSS, and use bootstrap's default `img { vertical-align: middle; }` CSS to align the text vertically.

```css
.imageClass {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 textContainer">
      <img class="imageClass" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg" alt="alt text">
      <span class="spanText">Need to center</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `display: flex;` on the parent with `align-items: center;` to align the flex children vertically.

```css
.textContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.imageClass {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 textContainer">
      <img class="imageClass" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg" alt="alt text">
      <span class="spanText">Need to center</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```